# This job run every 20s but noting saved in database, on the first time after first run the batch work but after that although the job is running

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

```
package com.wombatrack.configBatch;

import com.wombatrack.domain.entites.UserInstagram;
import com.wombatrack.service.UserInstagramService;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {

    @Bean
    ItemReader<UserInstagram> restUserInstagramReader(UserInstagramService userInstagramService) {
        return new RESTUserInstagramReader(userInstagramService);
    }

    @Bean
    ItemProcessor<UserInstagram, UserInstagram> restUserInstagramProcessor() {
        return new LoggingUserInstagramProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    ItemWriter<UserInstagram> restUserInstagramWriter() {
        return new LoggingUserInstagramWriter();
    }

    @Bean
    Step restUserInstagramStep(ItemReader<UserInstagram> restUserInstagramReader,
            ItemProcessor<UserInstagram, UserInstagram> restUserInstagramProcessor,
            ItemWriter<UserInstagram> restUserInstagramWriter,
            StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("restUserInstagramStep")
                .<UserInstagram, UserInstagram>chunk(5)
                .reader(restUserInstagramReader)
                .processor(restUserInstagramProcessor)
                .writer(restUserInstagramWriter)
                .allowStartIfComplete(true)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    Job restUserInstagramJob(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
            @Qualifier("restUserInstagramStep") Step restUserInstagramStep) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("restUserInstagramJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(restUserInstagramStep)
                .end()
                .build();
    }

}
```

**I have a probleme with this peace  of code my job run first time, but after that return user null that mean busness ligique of job run one time whene the application start first time**

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.BatchStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersInvalidException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRestartException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class BatchLauncher {
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    
    @Autowired
    private Job job;

    public BatchStatus run() throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException,
            JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {
        JobParameters parameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
                .toJobParameters();
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, parameters);
        return jobExecution.getStatus();
    }
    
}
```

** I put a schedular that will run every 20 seconds the job runs after every 20 seconds as expected, but the problem is that the business, i.e. the backup at the database level does not work no effect.
the job does its role only the first time after the application is started in the first time, but after that the scheduler makes the job run every 20 seconds but the information is not saved, I have a return every time the job with status COMPLETED but the job does nothing in terms of saving new data**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class Schedular {

    @Autowired
    private BatchLauncher batchLauncher;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 20000)
    public void perform() throws Exception {
        log.info("Batch programm&#xE9; pour tourner toutes les 20 secondes");
        batchLauncher.run();
    }
}
```

**I don't have any idea how to do it to fix this problem, i debug application but
I did not find any solution Please if someone can help me **

Comment: We have 0 insights into your system. A quick look over your code: "yes, that sounds reasonable". So, the only answer is: debugging is required. For example: simply add more LOG statements, for example in your BatchLauncher class. We have 0 idea what is going on in your system. We dont know your context, nothing.

Comment: Hard to say for sure, but if your `ItemReader` is stateful you'll need to annotate its bean factory method with `@StepScope`. Same may apply for the other components.